# Verify this condition with regular condition

Tags: java, regex

I have the following string:

```
"1,4,6,22,88,105:22"
```

How can I write a regular expression that checks the left part of the ':' and if one of the numbers is small than 'x' or greater than 'y' gives an error.

and then checks right part of the ':' and same range check of 'x' and 'y' ??

I'm new to regular expression and having difficulties making such expression.

Thank you!

Comment: You should use a split and compare the integers. A regex can't do comparisons of that sort intelligently.

Comment: Regex is definitely **not** the right tool for the job.

Comment: Using some tool like flex is trivial, using only a regex is not.

Comment: This is extremely easy with Java and nearly impossible with a regex.

Answer (score 1):

A regex is not a good tool to use for this.  You can do all you need by splitting and parsing the string: ([see it run](http://ideone.com/XOl84y))

```
class Main
{
  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
  {
        String inputString = "1,4,6,22,88,105:22";
        int min = 1;
        int max = 105;
        String[] splitString = inputString.split("[,:]");
        for (String part : splitString)
        {
            int parsedInt = Integer.parseInt(part);
            if (parsedInt < min || parsedInt > max)
                throw new Exception("Invalid");
        }
        System.out.println("Yay it's ok!");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for the answers, I'm doing split and in a for loop, I just thought that it might be possible with regex, but apparently not....